# How are CFX tags executed in Coldfusion 8?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, jrun

At my company, we have been running into some memory problems lately.  One thing we have done is increased the heap size in JRUN, but now we are noticing some side effects.

One of which is a CFX tag that processes images. When we use it, it cannot load the files we give it sometimes. Our current idea is that in order to process images, the whole image must be loaded into memory.  It only seems to throw errors on large files, which would take 200+ MB of memory to store the whole thing.

What I am wanting to know is how Coldfusion handles CFX tag loading and execution.  Since the CFX tag in particular was written in C++, I would think that it wouldn't necessarily use the Coldfusion heap (as it only stores Java data), and we are not seeing heap spikes when we process something.

I guess the major question is how the CFX gets executed: does it run as a thread under JRUN, or does a native Windows process get created that runs in its own user space?  And, if it does run under JRUN, what memory space does this use when executing, and is there a way to monitor it?

Answer (score 1):

A CFX definitely runs as a thread under JRUN and the data is marshalled from Java to C++ through the JNI layer. So yes it will load up the whole image into the heap using the default file open/read (under the covers) and then pass the binary to your C++ tag. Handling large image files (or large files in general) has always been an issue with CF in my view. There are some "pure Java" solutions for image handling that will provided for better performance - or you can use something like "imagemagik" which passes a filename and path to a shell and *is* executed separately. That's my take.

Comment: thanks for the response. if this data gets loaded into the heap, why are we not seeing spikes in the heap usage when we monitor with jconsole or visualvm?

Comment: I'm not sure... reporting maybe? jconsole reports on objects that are identified as short (eden) or long (tenured). This object is instantiated till it's fully read in and then it disappears pretty quickly.... but I'm not sure where it lives.I only know it's an issue we have battled over the years. file operations for large files in CF have always been iffy.

Comment: cool, thanks for the info.  we didn't see these problems popup until we increased the heap (sits at 1GB now), so we were wondering if this stuff got loaded outside of the coldfusion heap; if that were the case then it would make sense as the heap took up more memory that was being used from time to time to load these images up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you're running a 32-bit process, it can only access 2gig. If the heap is 1gig, then non-heap memory will be 60-200+ meg, then add in memory for each thread the process is running (and the number of threads goes even higher when you're clustered) then there sometimes isn't that much memory space left in your process. Plus, as I understand it, various DLLs are mapped into your memory space somewhere in the upper part of the memory range, meaning that when your image processing tag attempts to allocate a very large block of contigous memory (outside of heap is my guess), there's no single block left for it. This answer is somewhat speculative, so don't take it as gospel, but it may be worth looking at programs which can visualise a processes' memory map.

Comment: thanks for the response.  currently, we are using visualvm and jconsole to see inside the jvm, but when we use the cfx tag (whether successfully or unsuccessfully), we don't see spikes in memory usage, so it kind of tells me that this stuff gets executed outside the jvm.  do you have any tools to recommend for this?